# What is this group called?

Tags: group-theory, computer-science

Let $X$ denote a set. There's a corresponding group obtained by taking the group freely generated by $X^2$ and then quotienting out by the following families of relations:

1. $(x,x) = 1$
2. $(x,y)(y,z) = (x,z)$
3. $(x,y)(y,x) = 1$
4. For each quadruple $(x,y,x',y')$ such that $\{x,y\} \cap \{x',y'\} = \emptyset$, we have:
   $$(x,y)(x',y') = (x',y')(x,y)$$

> **Question.** What is this group called?

My motivation for considering this group is that it acts on the set $(\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N})^X,$ of $X$-many binary streams, by interpreting $(x,y)$ as the act of taking the first digit of stream $x$, removing it from $x$, and appending it to the beginning of $y$. Each of the four families above can be explained in these terms; for example $(x,x)=1$ is saying that if I take the first digit of stream $x$, and put it back on stream $x$, nothing changes.

Comment: I think rule three is redundant since $(x,y)(y,x)=(x,x)=1$ where the first equality is rule 2 and the second equality is rule 1.

Comment: @ASKASK, good point :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I think I can prove that the action you described is faithful as long as $X$ is infinite.  The abelianization of your group is just the subgroup of the free abelian group on $X$ consisting of elements whose coefficients sum to $0$ (send $(x,y)$ to $y-x$).   Assuming the action is faithful and $|X|>2$, the commutator subgroup can be described as the group of finite-support permutations of $X\times\mathbb{N}$ (think of the elements of the commutator subgroup as permuting the set of all the bits in all your binary streams).

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment:

The group you described has a neat equivalent characterization:

It can be described by the presentation $\langle a_1, a_2, ... , a_{|X| - 1}| [a_i, a_j] = [a_k, a_j] \forall i \neq j, j \neq k, k \neq i\rangle$

Proof:

Suppose, $X = \{0, ... , n\}$ ($|X| = n + 1$). Let's define $a_i := (0, i)$. That results in $(i, 0)$ being equal to $a_i^{-1}$ and for $i \neq j, j \neq 0, i \neq 0$ $(i, j) = a_i^{-1}a_j$. Now this change of notation already covers the first three rules, making them redundant.

Now, let's deal with the fourth rule. Without the loss of generality we can assume that one of the following cases takes place:

1)$x' = 0$, $x, y$ and $y' = z$ are pairwise distinct and non-zero. Then $(0, z)(x, y) = (x, y)(0, y')$, which turns into $a_{z}a_{x}^{-1}a_y = a_{x}^{-1}a_{y}a_{z}$ which results in $a_ya_za_y^{-1} = a_xa_za_{x}^{-1}$, or equivalently $[a_y, a_z] = [a_x, a_z]$

2)$x, y, x' = z$ and $y' = t$ are pairwise distinct and non-zero. Then $(x, y)(z, t)=(z, t)(x, y)$ turns into $a_x^{-1}a_ya_z^{-1}a_t = a_z^{-1}a_ta_{x}^{-1}a_y$ which is $(a_ya_z^{-1}a_y^{-1})(a_ya_ta_y^{-1})=(a_xa_z^{-1}a_x^{-1})(a_xa_ta_x^{-1})$ which is a direct corollary of case 1

Thus $[a_y, a_z] = [a_x, a_z]$ for all distinct $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the only non-trivial relations required.